# Three dozen or three dozens

Tags: pronouns, phrase-choice, adjective-phrases

> Three dozen of eggs are bought.

> Three dozens of eggs are bought.

Which expression is correct and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "dozen" can be used as both a number and as a noun.  As a number it isn't used in the plural.  Compare with "hundred":

> Three hundred eggs.

> Three dozen eggs  (not "of eggs")

> Hundreds of eggs  (as noun)

> Dozens of eggs (as noun)

Comment: Note that adjectives can be couple with "dozens" while a count would normally not be. For example "many dozens of eggs" is fine.

Comment: "dozen" works like "hundred", "thousand", etc. We use the singular for *a few dozen, a couple of million,...* but plural for *many thousands*. With some adjectival quantifiers, both "pluralities" are possible - particularly if further qualified by ***...of** [type].* But per [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=several+hundreds+of+people%2Cseveral+hundred+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), ***several hundreds** of people* is a declining usage compared to plain ***several hundred** people*. And the same applies with *several **dozen***.